# NSString converting to NSCFString

Tags: ios7, nsstring, xcode5, osc

I have created a category of `NSString` Class , and i am trying to do some custom `NSString` operation .
My `NSString` object is converting to `NSCFString` and its crashing at calling custom `NSString` method.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString stringByDeletingLastAndAddingFirstSlash]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa6015e0'

Comment: is `stringByDeletingLastAndAddingFirstSlash` method implemented ?

Comment: Yes . Its implemented.

Comment: show us some code please.

Comment: Your string isn't being converted — it was always an NSCFString.

Comment: Downvoters ..please leave a comment for reason ..

Comment: You'll need to show us specific bits of code otherwise your question is completely vague

Comment: OK, so you're asking "Why is my code crashing?" We have no way of telling why your code is crashing beyond "Your string does not respond do that selector." There is literally no information in this question that we could use to answer it.